# Creating objects on click button event

Tags: c#, .net

So there's data entry by the user, data manipulation by the code, and then save into a DB Table.

after the data entry i want to enter the given data to an object.

How can i, every time the user hits the New Expense button, create a new object ?

I know that creating an obj goes like

```
Classname c = new Classname();
```

But if i go like

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Classname c = new Classname();
}
```

isn't the program going to overwrite ? or create the object deleting the previous one?

I mean , these could both work, but in my case if the object gets overwritten i shouldn't create a new one, so i need to know what happens..

Comment: The "variable" is locally scoped - it only exists for the duration of the method (the proper name is actually "local", not "variable"). These are the very basics - you should probably pickup a book on C# and go through the first few chapters at least.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to be useful to future readers

Comment: @Micky - Thats subjective and not really a valid reason to close a question

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn how to program in C# (including ASP.NET), by reading online tutorials/books, or using Pluralsight, etc. If your current level experience means you need to ask a question like the above, then for you, writing an entire app (or maintaining an existing one) could result in having to ask many StackOverflow questions to help you out. That is going to frustrate you in the long term. Learn the basics first.

Comment: I am in the process of learning C# , the reason i wrote this piece of code was just because most of the answers with that question just stated how an obj is created.Im in the process of learning, i've read some books but not really got an answer to this question, maybe there's something i dont know . Hope i find it somehow hacking through people who delete questions! thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest keeping a collection of those objects for your form(or in another scope above the Button_Click method) and adding a new object to that in the event receiver like:

```
var coll = new List<Classname>();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        coll.Add(new Classname());
    }
```